# MapMarker.setCoordinate() stops updating the Position

Tags: android, geolocation, here-api, indoor-positioning-system

For a custom Positionindicator I use the MapMarker given by the Here SDK. The Location is obtained by Beacons. At some point i still receive new Location data in form of GeoCoordinates by the Beacons but the positioning of the MapMarker stops an it stays in a Position. After a while, lets say 100m, it updates the Position but then is stuck again. Did i miss something in my implementation?

```
  if (mPositionIndicator.getCoordinate() != geoCoordinate) 
       mPositionIndicator.setCoordinate(geoCoordinate);
```

the geocoordinate is updated  every second or less.

I can see the new positions... but the MapMarker stays in some old position.

the `geoCoordinate` i pass to the Map Marker looks like this : `new GeoCoordinate(52.xxxxxx , 13.xxxxxx)`

i tried to update the position  with removeMapObject and addMapObject, but still it dont updates when a new position is passed.

Update: 
A litte more information. I use some other framework to obtain the locationdata from the beacons and set this data to the mapmarker.

Comment: this issue is still there. How can i achieve a behavior like the position indicator with the map marker?

Answer (score 3):

In order to set a new position to a `MapMarker` you don't have to call `addMapObject()` again. It is enough to set the new position. For example the following code will create a `MapMarker` which is constantly moved up north each 100ms:

```
new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(true) {
                if (m_marker == null) {
                    m_latitude = 52.5;
                    Image image = new Image();
                    image.setBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image));
                    m_marker = new MapMarker(new GeoCoordinate(m_latitude, 13.4), image);
                    m_hereMap.addMapObject(m_marker);
                }
                // move marker north
                m_marker.setCoordinate(new GeoCoordinate(m_latitude += 0.00001, 13.4));
                sleep(100);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}.start();
```

Therefore I would suggest to isolate the issue. It should not matter if you use Beacons to receive updated indoor positions or HERE's `PositioningManager`.

Furthermore, in your implementation it looks a bit suspicious to compare the `GeoCoordinate` instances rather than comparing if latitude or longitude differ. Preferably use `geoCoordinate1.equals(geoCoordinate2)`.

Comment: Actually dont call 'map.addMapObject(marker)' all i do is add the  new GeoLocation with marker.setCoordinate. I changed my code to use .equals. No effect. The marker still stays at his old position.